# Inverse of structured block matrix

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, matrices, analysis, operator-theory

Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional vector space and consider the space $X=V\times V\times V\times V.$

Consider the block matrix

$$A = \begin{pmatrix} A_1 & A_2 \\ A_2^* & -A_1\end{pmatrix}$$

where $A_1 = \operatorname{diag}(\lambda_1,\lambda_2)$ for $\lambda_i \in \mathbb C$ and $A_2: V^2 \to V^2.$

We then consider $$K=(A-\lambda)^{-1}.$$

Question: Can we express the resolvent in the form

$$K = \begin{pmatrix} T_1(\lambda)(T_2-\lambda)^{-1} & * \\ * & T_3(\lambda) (T_4-\lambda)^{-1}\end{pmatrix}$$

where $T_1,..., T_4$ are some matrices and $T_1,T_3$ may depend smoothly on $\lambda$, whereas $T_2,T_4$ are independent of $\lambda$ and $*$ are elements I do not really care about.

Please let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: If we write $$K(\lambda) = \begin{pmatrix} K_{11}(\lambda) & K_{12}(\lambda) \\ K_{21}(\lambda) & K_{22}(\lambda)\end{pmatrix}$$, can't we just take $T_2,T_4$ arbitrary and $T_1(\lambda)=(T_2-\lambda)K_{11}(\lambda)$ and $T_3(\lambda)=(T_4-\lambda)K_{22}(\lambda)$ ?

Comment: @EwanDelanoy no, cause $T_1$ and $T_3$ may not depend smoothly on $\lambda$, they might have poles this way.

Comment: Have you tried writing down Schur complement ?

Answer (score 0):

Assume you have a block matrix

$$M=\begin{pmatrix}
A&B\\C&D
\end{pmatrix}.$$

Introduce a Feshbach map (also known as Schur complement)
$$a=A-BD^{-1}C.$$

Then we have
$$M^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix}
a^{-1}&-a^{-1}BD^{-1}\\-D^{-1}Ca^{-1}&D^{-1}+D^{-1}Ca^{-1}BD^{-1}
\end{pmatrix}.$$

In order to use this formula for your applications apply it to $M-\lambda E.$

Further reading:

- F. Zhang, The Schur Complement and Its Applications, Numerical
  Methods and Algorithms No. 4 (Springer, New York, 2005).
- Chapter 11 of S. J. Gustafson, Mathematical Concepts of Quantum Mechanics,
  2nd ed. (Springer, Heidelberg, 2011).